# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: spring, servlets, spring-ioc

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLPds.png)
I cannot get a Bean from the spring framework. Following is my code:

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="dao" />
    <bean id="dao" class="dao.ProduitDaoImpl" init-method="init">
    
    </bean>
    
</beans>
```

in the ControleurServlet.java I tried to appeal `springContext.getBean()` to have the `ProduitDaoImpl` object that is configured in applicationContext.xml but I got:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:

**ControleurServlet.java**

```java
package web;

@WebServlet(name="cs", urlPatterns={"*.do"}, loadOnStartup = 1)
public class ControleurServlet extends HttpServlet {
    
    @Autowired
    private IProduitDao metier;
    private static DataSource ds;
    
    
    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //super.init();
        //metier = new ProduitDaoImpl();
        System.out.println("Bean 'dao' retrieved from Spring context.");
        ApplicationContext springContext=WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(this.getServletContext());
        System.out.println("ApplicationContext initialized"+springContext);
        metier = (IProduitDao)springContext.getBean("dao");
        System.out.println("ProduitDaoImp initialized");
        try {
            // Perform JNDI lookup to obtain DataSource
            Context initContext = new InitialContext();
            Context envContext = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
            ds = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/myoracle");
            // Log success message if DataSource lookup is successful
            Logger.getLogger(ControleurServlet.class.getName()).info("DataSource lookup successful");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            // Log the NamingException if lookup fails
            Logger.getLogger(ControleurServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "NamingException occurred", e);
            // Print the exception stack trace for troubleshooting
        }
        
    }

}
```

**ProduitDaoImpl.java**

```
package dao;

@ComponentScan
public class ProduitDaoImpl implements IProduitDao {
    
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("Initialisation......"); 
    }

}
```

**web.xml**

```xml
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:**/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org. spring framework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

I expect to have an instance of `ProduitDaoImpl`

Comment: Thes no such bean in the context. You can't get it in the servlet `init()`. You should pass a servlet instance to spring autowiring factory to inject a bean to the servlet.